# Múltiples versiones de PHP en Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo un ligero problema, tengo que poner dos versiones de php en xampp, actualmente tengo la versión 8.1.4 pero para probar un proyecto mas antiguo necesito la versión 5.5.1
he buscado y intentado de todo y no se como realizarlo.
Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Lo que podrías es tener 2 instalaciones de xampp en diferentes carpetas. Teniendo así 2 paneles de xampp

Comment: pero no habría problemas al ejecutar?, por eso no lo he intentado

Comment: Si ejecutas ambas versiones a la vez sí, si cierras uno y luego abres otro no. Solo tendrás cerrar completamente uno de los xampp y luego a continuación abrir el otro.

Comment: wow voy a probar

Comment: @DanielaVargas, creo [esto es lo que estas buscando](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586592/3791844)

Comment: gracias!!! voy a intentarlo